# How to create a frame inside a frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can i create a frame inside a frame in python using Tkinter and then pack a button in one frame and when i press the button the ouput will be given on the second frame ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Nesting frames is exactly the same as putting a frame in the root window.

Answer (score 9):

We can add a frame inside a frame. Below code should achieve it.

```
import Tkinter
tk = Tkinter.Tk()
frame1 = Tkinter.Frame(tk, height = 100, width = 100, bg = "WHITE", borderwidth=2)
frame2 = Tkinter.Frame(frame1, height = 100, width = 100, bg = "RED", borderwidth=2)
frame1.pack()
frame2.pack()
label = Tkinter.Label(frame2, text = "Label") #Receive a callback from button here
label.pack()
button = Tkinter.Button(frame1,text="Button") #Send some action to Label here
button.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: My pleasure! I'm glad that it helped. If you're familiar with the process of [marking an answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), please do so. :) And to note, placing two frames over a main window does not help us in any new way. Most of the operations can be achieved in a single frame itself.

Comment: Note in the code that adding a Frame to a Frame is pretty much the same as adding any widget to a Frame.